# Cancel all event except the last one,

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to do this: suppose that there are a lot of same events fire a lot of times in a period of time, we will cancel all the previous event and only use the last one.

The last event will be for for one time only when there is no more event for 3 seconds.

For example: there is a button; we will let user click this button many times as they want and we will not disable this button. No matter how many times user have been clicking this we will consider it to be only one click count as the last click. The click event will be performed when there are no more clicks within 3 seconds.

Comment: Hi, [can you please provide some fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvczB/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as [debouncing](http://ajaxian.com/archives/debounce-your-javascript-functions). For this task there is already a superb [plugin/library from Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

```
(function() {
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
        func = Cowboy.debounce(1000, function() { console.log("click fired!"); });

    button.addEventListener("click", func);
}())​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngwzj/)

Comment: Cowboy is not compatible with jquery 1.7.2 .. still a great help anyway.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu That's not right ;) You've not tagged your question with jQuery so I thought you're looking for a vanilla JS solution. If jQuery is available, the plugin adds his two functions to the jQuery namespace instead of creating its own `Cowboy`. So instead of `Cowboy.debounce` you will have to use `$.debounce`. It's all documented on Ben Almans site :)

Comment: @Andreas yes i have tried that already as i have aware of that in the document. but it is not really compatible, someone else there also complain that it is not compatible in Jquery 1.7.1 anyway the knowledge of debounce helps me search another and i am using underscore right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var domButton = document.getElementById('some-button'),
    timeOut;
domButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.clientX && e.clientY) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        timeOut=setTimeout(function({document.getElementById('somebutton').click()},3000);
    }
},false)
```